# How can i apply css rules dynamically in a div after the user enters the rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building an online code editor for HTML/CSS/JS for a web technologies course.I used the ACE editor for the 3 respective editors from which i get the code submitted by the user and rewrite the contents of a div(result) in real-time.Everything happens client-side so i can't save the rules and import them(probably?).

I am having difficulties applying the css rules that the user inputs to the div that will diplay the result.For the HTML part i grab the code from the HTML editor and rewrite the code of the div with the result.I searched for a solution using jQuery but everything i tried failed.

Any ideas on how i can implement something like that?

```
var text2=editor2.getValue(); //Get the css rules that the user entered.
var newstyle=document.createElement("style"); //Create a <style> element
newstyle.innerHTML=text2;  //Add the rules in that element.
```

Then ,if i understood correctly the related answers i found online, i need to append the newstyle element in the head part of the code that is going to be written to the div with the result.I've tried with something like the following but i can't seem to get it right:

```
var t=document.getElementById("result"); //The div with the result of the code
t.appendChild(newstyle);
```

I suppose what i am missing is a way to insert the style element in the head element.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give us some code and explain more specifically the trouble you're having.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L9h55c37/1/

Comment: blex your solution seems to fit my needs just as well. I will try to integrate it in my code so that it works. Thank you for your help as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/7ku10n0t/27/

Inserting an element into the head can be done with document.head.appendChild. However, you'll want to make sure you don't try inserting the element multiple times, which (depending on browser) might cause some funky things to happen.

```
  <div>
        <textarea id="editor2" onblur="changeStyles();" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;"></textarea>
        <p class="class1">This is class 1</p>
        <p class="class2">This is class 2</p>
    </div>

<div>
    <textarea id="editor2" onblur="changeStyles();" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;"></textarea>
    <p class="class1">This is class 1</p>
    <p class="class2">This is class 2</p>
</div>

<script>    
function doOnLoad() {
    var newstyle = document.createElement("style"); //Create a <style> element
    newstyle.id = "customStyle";
    document.head.appendChild(newstyle);
};
// best practice is really to call this on DOMContentLoaded ($() for jquery)
doOnLoad();

function changeStyles() {
    var newstyle = document.getElementById("customStyle");
    var text2 = editor2.value; //Get the css rules that the user entered.
    newstyle.innerHTML = text2;  //Add the rules in that element.
}
</script>
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to insert the style-element in the HTML page. This way no JavaScript is needed to check if it exists and, if not, create it.

Comment: Thanks! Edited my answer to insert on load. Much better implementation... I guess I shouldn't be lazy in my example code :).

Comment: I will have to try the new code now :)



Leon, i also thought about adding the the style element from the start (empty) and later inserting there the css rules.I'm not sure though if i should (and how would i do it) rewrite the rules of the element every time a change is made or replace the whole element with a new one with the new rules.

Comment: Rewriting the InnerHTML on the existing element is more efficient. It depends on what you're trying to do though. If you want each style to be a new element (so that the style tags can interact with each other and the user can see those interactions), then assign an id to each style tag to separately edit.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work even with the code you provided. I am guessing it's because of something i did wrong elsewhere since i am pretty much a beginner on the subject. At least if i can understand your idea i might be able to reproduce the solution you offered me. So if i understand it correctly, i should create the style element on the html code onload and everytime a change is made on the css editor box i will rewrite the innerHTML of the style element to the contents of the editor.

Comment: Try this (I used JQuery since JSFiddle didn't seem to like my non-jquery code): http://jsfiddle.net/7ku10n0t/25/

Comment: I see from your fiddle that your code works the way i want it to.So it's obvious that i have to get it in line with the rest of my code to work because currently it doesn't. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you have HTML code you can insert it to your DOM using `jQuery(...).append()` or `jQuery(...).prepend()`.

To add a block of CSS to the `<head>` tag, you would write something like this:

```
jQuery("head").append(new_style);
```

If you prefer to add it to the `result` block, you can use:

```
jQuery("#result").prepend(new_style);
```

The `prepend()` is used to add it at the start.

See the docs for more info:

http://api.jquery.com/